# Trigger OnChanges by changing a property on the data bound object

Tags: angular

How can I get ngOnChanges() to trigger if a property on one of the data bound objects changes rather than having to set the property to a new object.

```
// component
@Input() myObj: ObjType;
// component code...
```

This doesn't trigger the change

```
// outside component
dataBoundObj.width = 1000;
```

This does

```
dataBoundObj = new ObjType();
```

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44857200/2545680) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular doesn't detect change when you mutate an object. However, it triggers `ngDoCheck` when checking current component. So you can perform a check yourself and trigger `ngOnChanges` from there:

```
ngDoCheck() {
   if (this.o.width !== this.oldWidth) {
      this.ngOnChanges();
   }
}
```